# What happens to application installed in playstore if i deploy module to app engine?

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, backend

I want to know what happens to users already installed applications, if i made any change in backend application and deploy module to app engine???

i.e i installed an application in play store yesterday with google storage backend in java. Now i wanted to add new feature to my existing app. but i am afraid if i did something wrong in backend application and deploy it to app engine, whether it will effect my installed application and users????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your already published app will be the same as when you published. If you had any communication with backend app will expect that backend will be working.

You can change anything in your backend as long as old endpoints will be working. If you need to make bigger update and remove some of elements in backend your app you should check version of backend API in your app and notify user about needed update of app.

Best way to check if everything is working is simply run existing app and verify if everything is ok. If anything broke up prepare fixed version of app and publish to play market as soon as possible. Users will get notification about update of your app. In that case they will have not working app until update.

Comment: oh... then i will create another backend module with same code and save data to new table and do my experiments here..so that my active users table in cloud will not be affected and as soon as i succeed will change my old backend module..isn't it??

Comment: sounds good. Do your development that way to not interfere your current users.